# ListView shows up blank when using ArrayAdapter<List<item>>

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

Im trying to pass some info from my fragment to my adapter to show a ListView and it does pass but the ListView doesnt show anything after its done loading.

I am sure that there is a problem with the adapter class.

(`item` is my custom class for the data Im passing)

Adapter code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List<item>> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<item> markers;
    private final static String[] a={"s"};


    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, List<item> markers) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item);
        this.context = context;
        this.markers = markers;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ProgressBar loader = (ProgressBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.loader);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemimgae);
        TextView views = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.views);
        TextView likes=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
        TextView upvote=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.upvote);
        TextView downvote=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.downvote);
        TextView desc=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        TextView pub =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pub);
        TextView idnum =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idnum);

        //Log.e("title",items.get(1).get(0));

        title.setText("      "+markers.get(position).getTitle());
//      views.setText(items.get(6).get(position));
//      likes.setText(items.get(7).get(position));
//      upvote.setText(items.get(8).get(position));
//      downvote.setText(items.get(9).get(position));
//      desc.setText(items.get(4).get(position));
//      pub.setText(items.get(5).get(position));
//      idnum.setText(items.get(0).get(position));


        return rowView;
    }
}
```

There are no errors in the logcat.

What's the problem here?

Comment: how you are setting the list adapter??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
 import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List<item>> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<item> markers;
    private final static String[] a={"s"};


    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, List<item> markers) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item);
        this.context = context;
        this.markers = markers;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ProgressBar loader = (ProgressBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.loader);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemimgae);
        TextView views = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.views);
        TextView likes=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
        TextView upvote=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.upvote);
        TextView downvote=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.downvote);
        TextView desc=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        TextView pub =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pub);
        TextView idnum =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idnum);

        //Log.e("title",items.get(1).get(0));

        title.setText("      "+markers.get(position).getTitle());
//      views.setText(items.get(6).get(position));
//      likes.setText(items.get(7).get(position));
//      upvote.setText(items.get(8).get(position));
//      downvote.setText(items.get(9).get(position));
//      desc.setText(items.get(4).get(position));
//      pub.setText(items.get(5).get(position));
//      idnum.setText(items.get(0).get(position));


        return rowView;
    }


     @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return markers.size();
    }



and then in your activity set the adapter as list.adapter();


}
```

Comment: Should I just add the getCount() method?

Comment: And what do you mean by setting the adapter in my activity? that is how I call the adapter: `setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(getActivity(), markers));`

Answer (score 2):

you have to pass the dataset, your `List<item>` to the super constructor of ArrayAdapter or override getCount and return `markers.size()`.

It could be   `super(context, R.layout.list_item, markers);`

or

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List<item>> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<item> markers;
    private final static String[] a={"s"};


    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, List<item> markers) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item);
        this.context = context;
        this.markers = markers;
    }


     @Override 
    public int getCount() {
        return (this.markers != null) ? this.markers.size() : 0;
    }

    // the rest of your code
}
```

Also I could suggest you three optimizations to the `getView` method:

1. ListView implements view recycle. You have to avoid the inflate and return everytime getView is called a new view.
2. Implement the ViewHolder patter
3. Retrieve the object once, as  @Raghunandan suggests, and access its member

Comment: also `Item item = markers.get(position)` and `item.getTitle()` considering Item is a class with getters and setters

Comment: Thanks to point it out. Still it is another issue :) @Raghunandan. Thanks for the editing

Comment: agreed just added so that you can post the same in your post and also consider using a view holder and to initialize inflater in the constructor rather than getView

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks but I need 1 more suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else...

I had the same problem (blank ListView items) and, in my case, it was caused by a bad layout width specification for the list row layout.

Do not use:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ...
```

Instead use:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ...
```

This only happened when I passed the parent in to the LayoutInflater (as I am supposed to) which made it frustrating to diagnose.